# Paypal Integration swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

Hi I'm new to using Paypal, I've started using paypal SDK but I can't find a way of turning the code below so my swift app delegate can pick it up can anyone inform me of **how I may be able to change the code below and change it so my swift file can pick it up ?**

```
[PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX"}];
```

Comment: This is not enough for us to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
PayPalMobile.initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments([PayPalEnvironmentProduction: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION", PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX"])
```